# Postgres - One Giant Table vs 10k+ Separate Tables - Partitioning

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

For the past 2 years we have trialed many different database engines and styles of database to solve a particular issue which needs both features of NoSQL and RDBMS packages.  We settled on RDBMS and Postgres.

We have performance tested many different scenarios and it shows that Postgres handles everything well all the time, but we know simulation is not production and other people have vastly differing experiences of databases at scale.

The One Giant vs many small is a well trodden argument, but my question is around efficiency on modest hardware at scale (modest hardware being starting out on a small linux VPS box, getting bigger and bigger as demand grows).

We have a single table (5 columns, 2 indexes (1 a three way index)), which will easily exceed 1bn rows.  If we have instead say 10(or even 100k) tables would this dilute the servers resources, in that the indexes would not all be able to be held in ram due to the shear number of tables?  If the data is split then pretty much all 10k table will be being read/written to so there is no particular active table as such.

And when discussing partitioning, because all of the partitions would be hot, I assume that this would also bring limited benefits given the wide spread of read/write activity.

So my question is: "With limited resources, does Postgres become inefficient when the data is partitioned in a single table or split across many tables.  Are there efficiencies to be gained by only having the one table index and nearly all of the activity being focussed around the end of the table."

Comment: *If* you aim for partitioning it's most probably worth waiting for Postgres 11 (to be released in Q4/2018) as that has substantial performance improvements for partitioned tables. Also: very often partial (aka "filtered") indexes already go a long way instead of partitioning.

Comment: So is it solved? I used to have a DB with 10k tables and pgAdmin loads really slow. I was thinking maybe use partitioning(same as multiple tables?), or use several big tables would help? But I'm not sure since 10K tables worked for me if I restrict my refreshing operation for whole db.

Answer (score 1):

It does not sound like you would get much benefit from partitioning.  If you go overboard and do 10k partitions, you could expect a lot of over head.  Even if you do something more reasonable like 100 partitions, if you use triggers to direct the tuples to the correct partition, that would still be a lot of overhead.  But splitting the index up shouldn't be a big problem from the perspective of fitting the data in RAM.  The aggregate amount of data would be pretty much the same whether partitioned or not.

Some benefits of partitioning even when you don't have a good key to partition on could be:

- You (or autovacuum workers) can vacuum each partition separately.  Unlike with one giant table, this can happen in parallel on the partitions. And if in serial, you still have the advantage that there are discrete chunks on which progress can be made conclusively.  If a table vacuum gets interrupted before completion, by system maintenance for example, it loses much of the work it accomplished and needs to be repeated; this can be a major problem with giant tables.
- If you need to add an index, you can add them to different partitions in parallel.  Or you can them add in serial, but with a large number of small maintenance windows, rather than one giant maintenance window.
- If you need to reindex (to cure index bloat, for example) same benefit as adding indexes.
- You can migrate partitions to different tablespaces, if you need to add storage but can't do an online expansion to your RAID.  Although you could probably add a partition in a different table-space to a previously un-partitioned table, too, so this may not be that much of a benefit.